# Connect to docker postgres socket from host via docker volumes

Tags: postgresql, sockets, docker, docker-compose

I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/postgresql/:/var/run/postgresql/:rw
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: dev
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw
```

I can connect to the postgres instance from my host as I have `5432` port forwarded to the host. I wanted to try connecting via the socket, but I am hitting issues. I'm not sure if this is possible?

From my host I can use the following:

```
psql --host=/Users/jalbert/Projects/postgres-sockets/tmp/postgresql -U username -d dev`

psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/Users/jalbert/Projects/postgres-sockets/tmp/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Although, I do see the socket file present there. If I go within the docker container I can connect via the socket no problem using a similar command.

Am I missing something to allow the host to use the socket connection? Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with the socket technologies.