# PostgreSQL: Can't Connect to Socket on Host via Volume in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

This is seemingly the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298887/connect-to-docker-postgres-socket-from-host-via-docker-volumes), though I thought I'd provide a simple example:

```
docker run -it \
  -v /pg_socket_on_host:/pg_socket_in_container \
  -e PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD} \
  postgres \
  psql -h /pg_socket_in_container -U postgres postgres
```

Where the path `/pg_socket_on_host` is a directory containing the file `.s.PGSQL.5432`. I've tried a few different versions of this, but I keep ending up with the same result:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/pg_socket_in_container/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Is there a reason that this is a problem with Docker?

Follow up:

I ensured that the permissions and the user (name and id, as well as group and id) for the host and container path/volume line up based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214423/cannot-use-mysql-socket-on-host-when-using-volumes), but I still get the same error. I am able to connect to the socket on the host machine from the host machine. I am also able to connect to the host via host.docker.internal from the docker container. Any other ideas about debugging strategies?